# Control template triggers cannot set value when used with StaticResource or x:Static

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

Strange issues I faced.

When trying to use `StaticResource` or `x:Static` with a converter from `ControlTemplate.Trigger` the converter `value` is always `NULL`.

In the below example the different usages are shown without any issues:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource Plus}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource Minus}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Plus}}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Minus}}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Plus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Minus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}"/>
</StackPanel>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <ContentControl Content="{x:Static icon:Icons.Plus}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{x:Static icon:Icons.Minus}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Plus}}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Minus}}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Plus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}"/>
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Minus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

The above code results in:

[image]

so far all good, both the `StaticResouce` and `x:Static` works fine, but the same examples when used within a `ControlTemplate.Triggers` then the converter gets `NULL` as `VALUE`

This is tested in .NET 4.5, 4.7.2 and 4.8 in VS 16.11.15 (2019)

**To reproduce:**

**MyResources.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Viewbox x:Key="Minus" x:Shared="False" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Width="32" Height="32" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0">
            <Rectangle Width="19" Height="19" Canvas.Left="6.49999" Canvas.Top="6.5" Stretch="Fill" StrokeMiterLimit="2.75" Stroke="#FF575756"/>
            <Rectangle Width="9" Height="2" Canvas.Left="11.5" Canvas.Top="15" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF1E5AA0"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

    <Viewbox x:Key="Plus" x:Shared="False" Stretch="Uniform">
        <Canvas Width="32" Height="32" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0">
            <Rectangle Width="19" Height="19" Canvas.Left="6.49999" Canvas.Top="6.5" Stretch="Fill" StrokeMiterLimit="2.75" Stroke="#FF575756"/>
            <Path Width="9" Height="9" Canvas.Left="11.5" Canvas.Top="11.5" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF1E5AA0" Data="F1 M 20.5,15L 17,15L 17,11.5L 15,11.5L 15,15L 11.5,15L 11.5,17L 15,17L 15,20.5L 17,20.5L 17,17L 20.5,17L 20.5,15 Z "/>
        </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Static classes**

```
//STATIC CLASS TO GET ICONS via x:Static
public static class Icons
{
    public static UIElement Minus => GetIconByName("Minus");
    public static UIElement Plus => GetIconByName("Plus");

    private static UIElement GetIconByName(string name)
    {
        try
        {
           return Application.Current.FindResource(name) as UIElement;
        }
        catch
        {
           return null;
        }
   }
}

//STATIC CLASS TO WRITE TO THE CONSOLE TEXTBOX
public static class Console
{
    public static void WriteLine(string message)
    {
        var console = ((MainWindow) Application.Current.MainWindow).Console;
        if (console == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(message);
            return;
        }
        console.Text = $"{message}\n{console.Text}";
    }
}

//STATIC EXTENSION CLASS FOR CHANGING COLORS
public static class Extensions
{
    public static UIElement ToRed(this UIElement element)
    {
        if (element == null) return null;
        var result = (UIElement)System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(element));

        result.ReColorAll(new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red));
        return result;
    }
    
    private static void ReColorAll(this DependencyObject element, Brush newColor)
    {
        if (element is null) return;
        for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(element); i++)
        {
            // Retrieve child visual at specified index value.
            var childVisual = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(element, i);
            switch (childVisual)
            {
                case Shape shape:
                    {
                        if (shape.Fill != null) shape.Fill = newColor;
                        if (shape.Stroke != null) shape.Stroke = newColor;
                        break;
                    }
                case GeometryDrawing drawing:
                    {
                        if (drawing.Brush != null) drawing.Brush = newColor;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            
            childVisual.ReColorAll(newColor);
        }
    }
}
```

**Converter class**

```
//CONVERTER CLASS TO CONVERTER ICONS TO RED
public class ToRedConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"PARAMETER: {parameter} - VALUE: {value}");
        var result = !(value is UIElement element) ? value : element.ToRed();

        return result;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfAllPurposesTest.MainWindow"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:icon="clr-namespace:WpfAllPurposesTest"
        Title="InfragisticsWindow" Width="700" Height="800">

    <Window.Resources>
        <icon:ToRedConverter x:Key="ToRed"/>

        <!--STYLE/TEMPLATE FOR TOGGLE BUTTON-->
        <Style x:Key="TreeToggleButtonStyle" TargetType="ToggleButton" x:Shared="False">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
                        <Grid Width="20" Height="20" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ExpandPath" Content="{Binding Path=Content, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--STYLE/TEMPLATE FOR TREEVIEWITEM-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="25"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition x:Name="RowToHide" Height="20"/>
                                <RowDefinition/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Name="BrdBackground" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0"/>
                            <!--VERTICAL LINE-->
                            <Border Name="VerticalLine" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="0">
                                <Path Data="M 5 1 L 5 9" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="Black" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Border>
                            <!--HORIZONTAL LINE-->
                            <Border Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Width="25">
                                <Path Data="M 12 12 L 25 12" StrokeThickness="0.5" Stroke="Black" Stretch="None"/>
                            </Border>
                            <!--EXPANDER / PLUS / MINUS ICON-->
                            <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Background="White" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                 ClickMode="Press" Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Plus}}" Style="{DynamicResource TreeToggleButtonStyle}" Visibility="Visible" Margin="0,0,2,0"/>

                            <!--TREE VIEW ITEM-->
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" ContentSource="Header" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
                            <!--TREE VIEW ITEM CHILDREN HOST-->
                            <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" />
                            <!--DUMMY BORDER TO MAKE ITEM AVAILABLE FOR MOUSE OVER AND SELECTION-->
                            <Border x:Name="TopBorder" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <!--TRIGGERS-->
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsExpanded" Value="false">
                                <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            </Trigger>

                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition SourceName="TopBorder" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="false"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Plus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}, ConverterParameter=CONVERTtview1}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="BrdBackground" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>

                            <MultiTrigger>
                                <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Condition SourceName="TopBorder" Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="false"/>
                                    <Condition Property="IsExpanded" Value="true"/>
                                </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Minus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}, ConverterParameter=CONVERTtview2}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="Expander" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="BrdBackground" Property="Background" Value="LightSkyBlue"/>
                            </MultiTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <!--STYLE/TEMPLATE FOR BUTTON-->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ContentControl Name="Temp_Content" Width="50" Height="50" Content="{StaticResource Plus}"/>
                            <ContentPresenter />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="Temp_Content" Property="Content" Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource Minus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}, ConverterParameter=CONVERTbtn}"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource Plus}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource Minus}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Plus}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Minus}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Plus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={StaticResource Minus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>


        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <ContentControl Content="{x:Static icon:Icons.Plus}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{x:Static icon:Icons.Minus}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Plus}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Minus}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Plus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding Source={x:Static icon:Icons.Minus}, Converter={StaticResource ToRed}}" Width="50" Height="50" Margin="10"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <TreeView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Width="200">
            <TreeViewItem Header="Parent 1">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 3"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 4"/>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Parent 2">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 3"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 4"/>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Parent 3">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 3"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 4"/>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Parent 4">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 3"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 4"/>
            </TreeViewItem>

            <TreeViewItem Header="Parent 5">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 1"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 2"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 3"/>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Child 4"/>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </TreeView>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
            <Button Content="Test"/>
            <Button Content="Test 1"/>
        </StackPanel>
         
        <TextBox  x:Name="Console" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" IsReadOnly="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(
            Application.LoadComponent(new Uri("WpfAllPurposesTest;component/MyResources.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
            ) as ResourceDictionary);

        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** While I was writing this question, I realized that this issue somehow is time dependent ?!?

If I immediately use the triggers somehow they work, but waiting a couple of seconds they don't

In the below example I waited a couple of second (finding shortcuts for recording):

[image]

When pointing at the `TreeViewItem`s and the `Background` turns blue, the icon disappears. Also the buttons in the middle does not have the icon from the trigger.

On the right side is the message from the Converter shown, and it shows that the correct trigger is triggered but the converter does not get the value.

In the below example, I was a little bit quicker with the recording short-cut:

[image]

In this example, the parent tree view items are shown correctly and icon is also changing, the message from converter shows also that the value is not null.

however for the second trigger which is triggered a little bit later and for the buttons it doesn't work.

Does any one know why this is happening or how to solve it ?

**UPDATE**

To remove all unnecessary focus and confusion.

This question is about the part:

```
 <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter ... Value="{Binding Source={StaticResource PlusRed}}"/>
      </Trigger>
 </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

In a `ControlTemplate.Trigger` when using the `Setter` with `{Binding Source={StaticResource...` It only reads the `StaticResource` for a brief moment after the compiling, if you wait a couple of seconds. it will not read it.

I removed all of the converters and the issue is still there...

**Conclusion:**

After some comments, the following comment of [@BionicCode](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3141792/bioniccode) cleared the confusion.

> The binding you are referring to is static. Binding is intended to bind to a value that can change. Binding will update the target of the source raiders a PropertyChanged event. Binding is not meant to set a referenced to an object. You use StaticResource for this purpose (see my answer)

In order to use the Converter I was creating a binding to a StaticResource which of course was not the intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it completely wrong and too expensive when it comes to performance. Also your styles contain redundant elements like the `"TopBorder"` in your `TreeViewItem` template and wrong trigger logic.

The proper way would be to define all resources in a XAML `ResourceDictionary` and reference them using the `StaticResource` markup. Don't use `x:Static` in this context.

Your algorithm to make elements red or change their color in general is very inefficient. For example you should not traverse the visual tree of the icon to change the `Background` of each element - even based on element type (which requires to implement a smelly type switch). Your current algorithm even requires XAML element de-/serialization. In other words, the overall performance is bad, which is totally unnecessary at this point.

You can replace this logic alongside the converter and simplify it by using data binding properly. This will also improve the performance.

I assume the desired behavior for the `TreeViewItem` expander is

- show "plus" icon when collapsed (to indicate can-be-expanded)
- show "minus" icon when expanded (to indicate can-be-collapsed)
- change icon background on mouse over to `LightSkyBlue`
- change icon stroke on mouse over to `Red`

When implementing triggers, you must give the templated element a default state.
Since the default of a boolean variable and therefore for the `ToggleButton.IsChecked` property of the expander is `false`, you should design the template based on the collapsed state. Then define triggers to change the appearance of elements when the state changes to expanded. This reduces the number of triggers and improves readability.

### Step 1: Implement dynamic Icons

Define your icons to allow dynamic coloring i.e. fill and stroke. This way we enable to set those attributes via data binding.
The following example expects the drawings to be hosted in a `ContentControl` (or a derived type like a `Button`). It uses the `ContentControl.Background` to color the icon's background (in this case the `Canvas.Background`) and the `ContentControl.Foreground` to color the strokes of the actual icon drawings.

To achieve this behavior we use `Bindig.RelativeSource` to bind to the `ContentControl` (the parent that will be added later in a different scope):

```xml
<Viewbox x:Key="MinusIcon"
         x:Shared="False"
         Stretch="Uniform">
  <Canvas Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Background}"
          Width="32"
          Height="32"
          Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0">
    <Rectangle Width="19"
               Height="19"
               Canvas.Left="6.49999"
               Canvas.Top="6.5"
               Stretch="Fill"
               StrokeMiterLimit="2.75"
               Stroke="#FF575756" /> <!-- Static border color (gray) -->
    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Foreground}"
               Width="9"
               Height="2"
               Canvas.Left="11.5"
               Canvas.Top="15"
               Stretch="Fill" />
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>

<Viewbox x:Key="PlusIcon"
         x:Shared="False"
         Stretch="Uniform">
  <Canvas Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Background}"
          Width="32"
          Height="32"
          Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0">
    <Rectangle Width="19"
               Height="19"
               Canvas.Left="6.49999"
               Canvas.Top="6.5"
               Stretch="Fill"
               StrokeMiterLimit="2.75"
               Stroke="#FF575756" /> <!-- Static border color (gray) -->
    <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Foreground}"
          Width="9"
          Height="9"
          Canvas.Left="11.5"
          Canvas.Top="11.5"
          Stretch="Fill"
          Data="F1 M 20.5,15L 17,15L 17,11.5L 15,11.5L 15,15L 11.5,15L 11.5,17L 15,17L 15,20.5L 17,20.5L 17,17L 20.5,17L 20.5,15 Z " />
  </Canvas>
</Viewbox>
```

### Step 2: Use dynamic icons in buttons

When you want to use the dynamic icons, you can host them in any `ContentControl`. You use `StaticResource` markup to reference the icon resources. And you reference it *directly* (without a `Binding` to the resource). For example

```xml
<Button Content="{StaticResource PlusIcon}" />
```

Again, you define a default state (in case of a button this is *not-clicked*) and define triggers that modify the element when the state changes. It is highly recommended to use the `VisualStateManager` instead of triggers.

To keep the answer technically as simple as possible, the following example uses triggers. They change the coloring of the icon and the icon itself (as of your requirement):

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
        <StackPanel>
          <ContentControl x:Name="IconHost"
                          Foreground="LightSkyBlue"
                          Background="Transparent"
                          Content="{StaticResource PlusIcon}"
                          Width="50"
                          Height="50" />

          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment" />
        </StackPanel>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="IconHost"
                    Property="Content"
                    Value="{StaticResource MinusIcon}" />
            <Setter TargetName="IconHost"
                    Property="Foreground"
                    Value="Red" />
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

### Step 3: Use dynamic icons in `ToggleButton` of `TreeViewItem`

You use the icons like in *Step 2*, by hosting them in a `ContentControl`.

The following snippet shows how to use the icon with the expander `ToggleButton`. You can move the setting of the `ToggleButton.Content` to a `Style`:

```xml
<ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
              Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="0" 
              Content="{StaticResource PlusIcon}"
              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
              Foreground="LightSkyBlue"
              IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded}"
              ClickMode="Press"
              Style="{DynamicResource TreeToggleButtonStyle}" 
              Visibility="Visible"
              Margin="0,0,2,0" /> <!-- Consider to use {StaticResource TreeToggleButtonStyle} when possible -->
```

### Step 4: Bringing it all together

The following example is an improved version of your `TreeViewItem` style. It fixes the incorrect trigger logic and highlight behavior.

The complete logic is implemented completely in XAML. It uses the in `Step 1` defined dynamic icons  and data binding to make the binding converter and extension methods obsolete.

The layout is improved, for example the redundant `"TopBorder"` is removed and all elements bind to the templated parent's `TreeViewItem.Background` property to fetch the current background highlight color (to reduce trigger setters).

Then the complete template is now based on the default state, which is the collapsed tree node. All attributes like `Visibility` and `Background` are configured accordingly.

The complete `TreeViewItem` style could look as follows:

```xml
<Window>
  <Window.Resources>

    <!-- Minus icon -->
    <Viewbox x:Key="MinusIcon"
             x:Shared="False"
             Stretch="Uniform">
      <Canvas Width="32"
              Height="32"
              Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0"
              Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Background}">
        <Rectangle Width="19"
                   Height="19"
                   Canvas.Left="6.49999"
                   Canvas.Top="6.5"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   StrokeMiterLimit="2.75"
                   Stroke="#FF575756" />
        <Rectangle Width="9"
                   Height="2"
                   Canvas.Left="11.5"
                   Canvas.Top="15"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Foreground}" />
      </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

    <!-- Plus icon -->
    <Viewbox x:Key="PlusIcon"
             x:Shared="False"
             Stretch="Uniform">
      <Canvas Width="32"
              Height="32"
              Clip="F1 M 0,0L 32,0L 32,32L 0,32L 0,0"
              Background="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Background}">
        <Rectangle Width="19"
                   Height="19"
                   Canvas.Left="6.49999"
                   Canvas.Top="6.5"
                   Stretch="Fill"
                   StrokeMiterLimit="2.75"
                   Stroke="#FF575756" />
        <Path Width="9"
              Height="9"
              Canvas.Left="11.5"
              Canvas.Top="11.5"
              Stretch="Fill"
              Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContentControl}, Path=Foreground}"
              Data="F1 M 20.5,15L 17,15L 17,11.5L 15,11.5L 15,15L 11.5,15L 11.5,17L 15,17L 15,20.5L 17,20.5L 17,17L 20.5,17L 20.5,15 Z " />
      </Canvas>
    </Viewbox>

    <!-- Button style -->
    <Style TargetType="Button">
      <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
          <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
            <StackPanel>
              <ContentControl x:Name="IconHost"
                              Width="50"
                              Height="50"
                              Foreground="LightSkyBlue"
                              Background="Transparent"
                              Content="{StaticResource Plus}" />
              <ContentPresenter />
            </StackPanel>

            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                       Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="IconHost"
                        Property="Content"
                        Value="{StaticResource Minus}" />
                <Setter TargetName="IconHost"
                        Property="Foreground"
                        Value="Red" />
              </Trigger>
            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
          </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </Window.Resources>

  <TreeView>
    <!-- TreeViewItem style -->
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="TreeViewItem">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
                Value="{x:Null}" />
        <Setter Property="Background"
                Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
          <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="TreeViewItem">
              <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
                  <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                  <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                  <RowDefinition x:Name="RowToHide"
                                 Height="20" />
                  <RowDefinition />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                <Border Name="BrdBackground"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                        BorderBrush="Gray"
                        BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" />

                <!--VERTICAL LINE-->
                <Border Name="VerticalLine"
                        Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.RowSpan="2"
                        Grid.Column="0">
                  <Path Data="M 5 1 L 5 9"
                        StrokeThickness="0.5"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        Stretch="Fill"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                </Border>

                <!--HORIZONTAL LINE-->
                <Border Grid.Row="0"
                        Grid.Column="0"
                        Width="25">
                  <Path Data="M 12 12 L 25 12"
                        StrokeThickness="0.5"
                        Stroke="Black"
                        Stretch="None" />
                </Border>

                <!--EXPANDER / PLUS / MINUS ICON-->
                <ToggleButton x:Name="Expander"
                              Grid.Column="0"
                              Grid.Row="0"
                              Content="{StaticResource PlusIcon}"
                              Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                              Foreground="LightSkyBlue"
                              IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsExpanded}"
                              ClickMode="Press"
                              Style="{DynamicResource TreeToggleButtonStyle}"
                              Visibility="Visible"
                              Margin="0,0,2,0" /> <!-- Consider to use {StaticResource TreeToggleButtonStyle} when possible (to improve performance) -->

                <!--TREE VIEW ITEM HEADER -->
                <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_Header"
                                  Grid.Column="1"
                                  Grid.Row="0"
                                  ContentSource="Header"
                                  HorizontalAlignment="Left" />

                <!--TREE VIEW ITEM CHILDREN HOST-->
                <ItemsPresenter x:Name="ItemsHost"
                                Grid.Row="1"
                                Grid.Column="1"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                Visibility="Collapsed" />
              </Grid>

              <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                         Value="false">
                  <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                          Property="Visibility"
                          Value="Collapsed" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsExpanded"
                         Value="True">
                  <Setter TargetName="ItemsHost"
                          Property="Visibility"
                          Value="Visible" />
                  <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                          Property="Content"
                          Value="{StaticResource MinusIcon}" />
                </Trigger>

                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                         Value="True">
                  <Setter Property="Background"
                          Value="LightSkyBlue" />
                  <Setter TargetName="Expander"
                          Property="Foreground"
                          Value="Red" />
                </Trigger>
              </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
          </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
      </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
  </TreeView>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thank you very much to the extended answer and for pointing out the issues. I really do appreciate the effort. But you focused on the wrong problem. Now the examples in the question were made to create a minimal reproducible example. In reality the issue has not much to do with TreeViewItem or Button. But generally in ControlTremplate.Triggers, which should be totally valid. Even in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/treeview-styles-and-templates?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) they use both triggers and Visual state manager.

Comment: By the way... the unnecessary TopBorder somehow was necessary as IsMouseOver covers the whole TreeViewItem, also the children. IsMouseDirectlyOver somehow didn't work and I had to improvise with the TopBorder. I will give the visual state manager a try and update the question with the result. But for now the question remains unanswered

Comment: You should trigger on the templated parent's IsMouseOver. If my post doesn't answer your question then you must improve it, please. You made it like you want to make your icons work in the context of user interaction. My answer also gives you an example on how to reference resources and how to switch the reference using a trigger. The answer targets your exact question. Maybe you don't understand my answer? I'm willing to improve it but your critique was not very helpful.

Comment: In general, using triggers is fine. But controls usually define explicit visual states which you can find in the API docs. Handling those explicit states using the VisualStateManager offers more flexibility and sometimes even avoids strange behavior of the customized i.e. templated control.

Comment: I am not trying to critique you. Not all, in matter of fact I do really appreciate the answer, which to a certain point I totally agree with you. But the point is somewhere totally different. I may have focused too much on the wrong point as well... which I have made an update of now.

Comment: *"Now the examples in the question were made to create a minimal reproducible example. In reality the issue has not much to do with TreeViewItem or Button."* - My question targets your exact question i.e. your rendered scenario. If you are not able to extract the information based on your own chosen abstraction level, then you probably asked the wrong question. The answer shows how to reference resources and how to use a trigger to swap them - if this is what you are really interested in.

Comment: From my point of view,  you got what you asked for. It's up to you to ask follow up questions to help you to understand the answer or improve your question.

Comment: Again I do appreciate the answer. But it does not cover the question of why {Binding Source={StaticResouce ...}} only works for a brief moment and the afterwards stops working. That is the real question.

Comment: *"I am not trying to critique"* - I was not saying this to express bad feelings. I appreciate your critique if it enablrs me to improve my answer. Your critique is valid and valuable to me.

Comment: The binding you are referring to is static. Binding is intended to bind to a value that can change. Binding will update the target of the source raiders a PropertyChanged event. Binding is not meant to set a referenced to an object. You use StaticResource for this purpose (see my answer).

Comment: Right... now I'm with you... Had totally missed that point...

Comment: Sorry for this crazy typing. I was sending the message from my mobile. Auto complete messed around again. I hope you could understand what I was trying to say. I have to apologize!

Comment: No worries, thanks a lot for the effort, I now get it.